# Can I control hair thickness with weight values?

Tags: particles

Can I adjust the thickness of my hair using alpha texture or weight values in Blender? This is a must for natural hairdressing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to add Alpha to the tips of the hairs, using a **Hair Info Node**. This will require you to use Cycles. 
I just pulled this here straight out of the Cycles Encyclopedia by Blender Guru. 
https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-input-encyclopedia

[image: Cycles Hair Info Node to use Hair Thickness to change its render properties]

[image: Node Setup]

You can also use the **Strand Settings** to scale all hair equally.

[image: Cycles Strand Settings]

I am checking to see whether you can feed in a texture or a vertex map to drive the render attributes, so you could paint in the width of the scale of the individual strands. Can't tell you off the cuff if that is possible, but I would find it useful, too.